# Expression variables have been defined for constraint interface ... while Expression Language is not enabled

Tags: bean-validation

I have project, with some custom ConstraintValidator. I wanted to build custom message. I did so and everyting works just fine. Then we met need to have 'api' module, which means, that you have to split bean validation annotation and ConstraintValidator, have to use `@Constraint(validatedBy = {})` and setup pairing manually using ConstraintMapping. Everyting stil works, except for message interpolation.

Log now contains kinda cryptic message:

```
Expression variables have been defined for constraint interface whatever.SomeValidation while Expression Language is not enabled.
```

All of that while I'm literary using the same code as one mentioned here:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_contexts
to disableDefaultConstraintViolation and register custom one.

Any ideas what can cause that?

Comment: It's very weird, that before (I'll present more info in answer) it worked without it, but after split one has to explicitly call `enableExpressionLanguage()` on `HibernateConstraintViolationBuilder`. I was overlooking that possibility due problems with dependencies versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a security update in Hibernate Validator. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#el-features for more details, but in a nutshell, around Hibernate Validator 6.x (which got into Spring Boot 2.6.x releases) default usage of template variables & bean properties and methods in custom validators was deemed a security risk and was disabled by default. You need to re-enable them by providing corresponding properties to validator beans via `META-INF/validation.xml` (which would go to e.g. `src/main/resources/META-INF/validation.xml` in usual Spring Boot setup) containing e.g.

```
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration" version="1.1">
    <property name="hibernate.validator.custom_violation_expression_language_feature_level">variables</property>
</validation-config>
```

, or, alternatively, via configuring the `ValidatorFactory`, e.g.

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = 
    Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )   
        .configure()
        .customViolationExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel(ExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel.BEAN_METHODS)
        .buildValidatorFactory();
```

or

```
Configuration<?> config = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();
((ConfigurationImpl)config).constraintExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel(
    ExpressionLanguageFeatureLevel.BEAN_METHODS);

ValidatorFactory factory = config.buildValidatorFactory();
```

---

In general, these levels are defined using the following properties:

```
hibernate.validator.constraint_expression_language_feature_level

hibernate.validator.custom_violation_expression_language_feature_level
```

Accepted values for these properties are:

- `none`
- `variables`
- `bean-properties`
- `bean-methods`